# difference between strings and striped_strings in beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html, python-beautifultable

What is difference between strings and stripped_strings in BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://codewithharry.com"
r = requests.get(url)
htmlcontent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find(id="imgpreview2")

# Using strings method
for item in tags.strings:
    print(item)

# Using stripped_strings method
for item in tags.stripped_strings:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Stripped Strings:**
it omits lines that consist of just empty spaces, and also removes leading and trailing spaces.

**Strings**: it does not omit lines with spaces or leading trailing space and contain \n etc.

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>   This is some text.   </p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div_tag = soup.find('div')

print("strings method:")
for item in div_tag.strings:
    print(repr(item))

print("\nUsing stripped_strings method:")
for item in div_tag.stripped_strings:
    print(repr(item))
```

**Output**:

```
strings method:
'\n'
'   This is some text.   '
'\n'
'\n'
'Item 1'
'\n'
'Item 2'
'\n'
'\n'

Using stripped_strings method:
'This is some text.'
'Item 1'
'Item 2'
```